# How can a Wizard tank Izual in Inferno without gaining any damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just saw a Wizard with 4700 HP in Inferno using *Force Armor*. He tanked Izual without gaining any damage. I asked him how he did that, but I got no answer.

How is this possible? Are Wizards the new tanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy Armor glyphed with Force Armor has recently been changed in a hotfix:

> Amount of damage absorbed from a single attack will now cap at 100% of a player’s maximum Life

[source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5825330)

Force Armor before the hotfix, combined with Diamond Skin, allowed the Wizard to absorb incredible amounts of damage. This worked by Force Armor reducing the amount of damage from any one hit to 65% of the Wizard's health, and then Diamond Skin absorbing that amount. This did make Wizard's "Tanks" for about one week.

This is no longer the case.